# Meaning of Whiplash in this context

Tags: meaning

The Governor's voice was a WHIPLASH now.., meaning of whiplash here. The line is from my grade 12 book

Comment: more context needed

Comment: This is metonymy. You may well not find this sense in a dictionary. The Governor's voice was as sharp and loud as the sound of a whip cracking (and there's the connotation of harshness or even cruelty).

Comment: It's a metaphor I'd say. Look the word up in a dictionary. Please cite the title of the story where this line was taken from. Thanks :)

Comment: @Edwin..you helped me! now i got the answer of my query. You could have posted it as an answer.

Comment: Definitely *not* metonymy. Would be simile if it was ***like** a whiplash*, but it isn't, so it's meta for something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## [Whiplash](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/whiplash)

> The lash of a whip - dictionary.com

Whiplash is being used figuratively here. The Governor is causing pain, like a whip, with their words.